# Integrating Oauth.io in to a React Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, oauth.io

I have a button that I'm using in a Chrome extension to connect to Twitter. When I click connect using the following code:

```
OAuth.popup('twitter').done(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
}, function(result) {
  debugger
});
```

The window pops up and closes right way. Debugging gives me this message:

`Origin "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/" does not match any registered domain/url on oauth.io`

Any idea what might be stopping it from working properly?

Comment: I referred to this: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/issues/52 and added: `"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["https://oauth.io/*"]
},` to the manifest.json, but no change.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding `https://mail.google.com` to the listed of accept URLs in oauth.io.